# C++ Linker Errors - error LNK2005: ... already defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, linker, linker-errors

I have a project that builds correctly in x64 bit but throws errors looking like this in 32bit:
libeay32-s-MT.lib(err.obj) : error LNK2005: _ERR_error_string already defined in libcrypto.lib(libcrypti-1_1.dll)

There's a list of these but they all look similar. Not sure if this is related with the fact that it throws the error in 32 bit, or whether it's something else in the configuration. Anyone had something similar? I am using VS2017 and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the problem comes from the library file. Please check whether there is a problem with duplicate definitions and the compatibility of the library. I suggest you read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2005?view=msvc-170), which provides some solutions for your reference.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with a VC Distributable or a Visual Studio update. This used to work fine and it works well for my teammates.

Comment: According to your description, the problem is difficult to troubleshoot. The [release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=release%20note%20visual%20studio%20) can view some major changes in the new version of VS, and you can use these documents to troubleshoot the cause of the error. In addition, the update of VS will affect the cache, which may also be the cause of the error. If the above methods cannot solve your problem, I suggest you go to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=62&entry=problem) to report the problem.